# Can't make my student java program to work with a class that is in a .jar file

Tags: java, jar, import

I am using jsoup HTML parser library to parse html in my homework program.

At first, I import what I consider is required to be imported:

----myprogramm.java----

```
...
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.parser.*;
import org.jsoup.safety.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
...
[actual program code]
```

-----end myprogramm.java----

I've put the jsoup.jar file in the same directory where myprogramm.java is.

Then:

```
javac -classpath "./jsoup.jar" MyProgramm.java 
java -cp "./jsoup.jar" MyProgramm "first string argument" "second string argument"
Error: Could not find or load main class MyProgramm //this is my translation form german
```

I've tried a lot of variations Of -cp argument but no success so far...

Comment: You also need the resulting `MyProgramm.class` on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MyProgramm has no package defined, and the directory you are in is where the MyProgramm.class file is, do

```
java -cp .:./jsoup.jar MyProgramm

     if on linux
```

or

```
java -cp .;./jsoup.jar MyProgramm

     if on windows
```

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X 10.8. I've tried the one for Linux and it gave the same result as before.